# List to string without first comma

Tags: java

I want to let `groupsId` to  `1,2,3`
But my code with comma in first.  `,1,2,3`
How to edit this??

```
  groupsId = [1,2,3]     
    String id = ""; 
    for(int i = 0  ; i < groupsId.size() ; i++)
     {
         if(i>=0)
             id += "," + groupsId.get(i);
     }
```

By the way , if `groupsId` can be `(1,2,3)` format would be great

Comment: if (i>0) {// put a comma}

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want use loops and handling loops by yourself, let Java do that for you:

```
Integer[] groupsId = {1,2,3};
String id = Arrays.deepToString(groupsId);
id = id.replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Very efficient solution, you don't see `deepToString()` all too often.

Comment: i think he has List not array

Comment: If groupsId is a List it would be easier. You need only to change this:   String id = groupsId.toString();  And the other lines would be the same.

Comment: @STaefi are u sure after .toString your Arrays.deeptoString will work?

Comment: @Hiru: If the groupsId is a List, Just replace the Arrays.deepToString(groupsId) with groupsId.toString().

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your handling of the 0th index. You don't want to add a comma in that case.

```
groupsID = [1,2,3]; //pseudo code for a List?  
String id = ""; 
for(int i = 0; i < groupsId.size(); i++)
 {
     if(i==0)
         id += groupsId.get(i);
     else
         id += "," + groupsId.get(i);
 }
```

Or if you can assure your `groupsId` has a length greater than 0...

```
groupsID = [1,2,3]; //pseudo code for a List?
String id = "(" + groupsId.get(0); 

for(int i = 1; i < groupsId.size(); i++)
 {
     id += "," + groupsId.get(i);
 }
id+= ")";
```

Above example also outputs array items surrounded by parentheses `(1,2,3)`, as requested. You should be able to piece together the differences between this solution and my first.